# Looking to combine two methods with c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, refactoring

HI all i have below two methods and looking to combine both and one method does not need any joins and other method need those how can i combine these two methods

```
    internal static IQueryable<ConstructionSet> CalculateSelectedConstructionSetsForOSM(Guid? ashraeClimateZoneId,
                                                                                        Guid? energyCodeId,
                                                                                        Guid? massingTypeId,
                                                                                        APIDbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        }

        return dbContext.ConstructionSets.Include(p => p.AshraeClimateZone)
                                         .Include(p => p.MassingType)
                                         .Include(p => p.SourceOfData)
                                         .Include(p => p.ExteriorWall)
                                         .Include(p => p.ExteriorFloor)
                                         .Include(p => p.InteriorFloor)
                                         .Include(p => p.InteriorWall)
                                         .Include(p => p.SlabOnGrade)
                                         .Include(p => p.BelowGradeWall)
                                         .Include(p => p.Glazing)
                                         .Include(p => p.Roof)
                                         .Where(p => p.AshraeClimateZoneId == ashraeClimateZoneId
                                         && p.SourceOfDataId == energyCodeId
                                         && p.MassingTypeId == massingTypeId
                                         && p.Revision != null
                                         && p.IsApproved == true)
                                         .AsEnumerable()
                                         .OrderByDescending(i => i.Revision)
                                         .GroupBy(i => i.InitialRevisionId)
                                         .Select(g => g.First()).AsQueryable();
    }
```

the below one is another method

```
    internal static IQueryable<ConstructionSet> CalculateSelectedConstructionSetsForProject(Guid? ashraeClimateZoneId,
                                                                                            Guid? energyCodeId,
                                                                                            Guid? massingTypeId,
                                                                                            APIDbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        }

        return dbContext.ConstructionSets.Include(p => p.AshraeClimateZone)
                                         .Include(p => p.MassingType)
                                         .Include(p => p.SourceOfData)
                                         .Where(p => p.AshraeClimateZoneId == ashraeClimateZoneId
                                         && p.SourceOfDataId == energyCodeId
                                         && p.MassingTypeId == massingTypeId
                                         && p.Revision != null
                                         && p.IsApproved == true)
                                         .AsEnumerable()
                                         .OrderByDescending(i => i.Revision)
                                         .GroupBy(i => i.InitialRevisionId)
                                         .Select(g => g.First()).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Could any one please let me know how can i combine these methods, many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'combine them'.  Are you just wanting to concatenate the values together?
Have you tried 'concat'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "combine them" you mean "refactor them so a single method can handle both cases", you can do something like this:

```
internal static IQueryable<ConstructionSet> CalculateSelectedConstructionSets(Guid? ashraeClimateZoneId,
                                                                                    Guid? energyCodeId,
                                                                                    Guid? massingTypeId,
                                                                                    APIDbContext dbContext,
                                                                                    bool includeOsmNavigationProperties)
{
    if (dbContext is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }

    var sets = dbContext.ConstructionSets.Include(p => p.AshraeClimateZone)
                                     .Include(p => p.MassingType)
                                     .Include(p => p.SourceOfData);
    if(includeOsmNavigationProperties)
    {
        sets = sets.Include(p => p.ExteriorWall)
                                     .Include(p => p.ExteriorFloor)
                                     .Include(p => p.InteriorFloor)
                                     .Include(p => p.InteriorWall)
                                     .Include(p => p.SlabOnGrade)
                                     .Include(p => p.BelowGradeWall)
                                     .Include(p => p.Glazing)
                                     .Include(p => p.Roof);
    }
    return sets.Where(p => p.AshraeClimateZoneId == ashraeClimateZoneId
                                     && p.SourceOfDataId == energyCodeId
                                     && p.MassingTypeId == massingTypeId
                                     && p.Revision != null
                                     && p.IsApproved == true)
                                     .AsEnumerable()
                                     .OrderByDescending(i => i.Revision)
                                     .GroupBy(i => i.InitialRevisionId)
                                     .Select(g => g.First()).AsQueryable();
}
```

As a side note, you should avoid the pattern of converting this to `.AsEnumerable()` and then back to `.AsQueryable()`. Making the result an `IQueryable` makes subsequent operations on the returned collection much slower (expressions need to be compiled at run-time), and it hides the fact that you won't be performing subsequent operations at the database layer. Someone might add a `Where()` clause and not realize that they're still causing the entire set of data to get loaded out of the database.

Comment: many thanks for the response and i removed that conversion.